# How to create secret in k8s using Ansible-K8s Module

Tags: kubernetes, ansible

I wanted to created k8s secret using Ansible-k8s modules.
While I am  able to create secret with kubectl secret command , but i need to create with Ansible-k8s module.

Request you to help me .
Thanks in advance

Comment: You have failed to specify what you have already tried, and what error message it is producing for you. Have you already read [the fine manual](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/collections/community/kubernetes/k8s_module.html#examples)?

Comment: i need an sample example on how to create secret using ansibe-k8s . The link provided does not show secrets creation .I searched many blogs , but non of them showed example of secret using ansible-k8s . Kindly suggest

Answer (score 5):

While there is no example on how to create a secret, there are examples which show how Kubernetes definitions can be used.

Suppose you have a `mysecret.yaml` file like below:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret

metadata:
  name: mysecret
  namespace: default

type: Opaque

data:
  username: YWRtaW4=
  password: MWYyZDFlMmU2N2Rm
```

**Option 1:**

Load the definitions from the above file:

```yaml
- name: create k8s secret mysecret
  k8s:
    src: mysecret.yaml
    state: present
```

**Option: 2:**

Put the definition of secret in-line:

```yaml
- name: create k8s secret mysecret
  k8s:
    definition:
      apiVersion: v1
      kind: Secret

      metadata:
        name: mysecret
        namespace: default

      type: Opaque

      data:
        username: YWRtaW4=
        password: MWYyZDFlMmU2N2Rm
    state: present
```

Comment: How to use an existing `htpasswd` file? Like: `kubectl create secret generic auth-secret --from-file=/registry/auth/htpasswd`